# "Error Setting TCP Socket Options" error with setsockopt()

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, setsockopt

This snippet is taken from `server.c`, which is supposed to be receiving data from a client machine:

```
int main() {
    int sock, client_socket;
    char buffer[1024];
    char response[18384];
    struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;
    int i = 0;
    int optval = 1;
    socklen_t client_length;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *) &optval, sizeof(optval)) < 0) {
        printf("Error Setting TCP Socket Options!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.188");
    server_address.sin_port = htons(12345);

    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    listen(sock, 5);
    client_length = sizeof(client_address);
    client_socket = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &client_length);
```

When I compile and run this on Kali Linux, it sets the TCP socket fine and works, but when I compile and run this on Windows with gcc `gcc server.c -o server.exe -lws2_32`, I get the error message from `setsockopt()`:

> Error Setting TCP Socket Options!

Below this snippet is the `bind()` and `listen()` function, along with `if/else` block deciding what to do with the data received from the client.

Comment: And what is `errno` set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you must call [`WSAStartup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) before using any other socket functions (and call [`WSACleanup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsacleanup) when you are done using the Winsock library before exiting). Other platforms don't have similar functions to initialize/cleanup their socket libraries.

And, you should always check the return values of socket functions (or any system call)  for failure, and use [`WSAGetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror) (`errno` on other platforms) to retrieve error codes to tel, you *why* the functions failed.

You are not checking if `socket()` fails (which would report a `WSANOTINITIALISED` error), so you are then passing an invalid socket to `setsockopt()` (which would report a `WSAENOTSOCK` error).

Try this:

```
int main() {
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET sock, ...;
    ...
    BOOL optval = TRUE;
    ...

    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsa);
    if (err != 0) {
        printf("Error Initializing WinSock! Error: %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("Error Creating TCP Socket! Error: %d\n", err);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *) &optval, sizeof(optval)) < 0) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("Error Setting TCP Socket Options! Error: %d\n", err);
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    ...
```